# How to take child's children values in parent using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not very familiar with SQL.

I have 3 tables, which relates to each one as one to many. Mean for one `History` have many `Applications`, but for one `Application` have many `ApplicationAttributes`.

I need to show `EnrolledTotal` column in `Histories` request for each `History`'s `Application`, where name `LIKE = '%Enrollment%'`.

Please can anybody help me?

Histories table:

```
Id  Imei                  CreationDate   DeviceId
1   ProductionDevice299   2018-11-04     1
7   ProductionDevice300   2018-11-09     1
```

Applications table:

```
Id  Name              DeviceHistoryId
1   Enrollment.cone   1
2   DPC_OWNERS        1
3   OTHER_APPS        1
6   Enrollment.emp    7
7   DPC_OWNERS        7
```

ApplicationAttributes table:

```
Id  Key             Value   DeviceApplicationId
1   EnrolledTotal   2       1
2   LoginsTotal     5       2
3   OtherAttribt1   8       3
4   OtherAttribt2   12      3
5   OtherAttribt3   17      3
6   EnrolledTotal   21      6
7   LoginsTotal     25      7
```

**Expected result:**

```
Id  Imei                  CreationDate   DeviceId   EnrolledTotal
1   ProductionDevice299   2018-11-04     1          2
7   ProductionDevice300   2018-11-09     1          21
```

My current sql query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[Imei] AS [imei], 
CAST([Extent1].[CreationDate] AS DATE) AS [lastSeenOnline],  
[Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [deviceId]

FROM [DeviceManagement].[dbo].[DeviceHistory] AS [Extent1]

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Imei], max([CreationDate]) as MaxDate
    FROM [dbo].[DeviceHistory]
    GROUP BY [Imei], CAST([CreationDate] AS DATE)
) [Extent2] on [Extent1].[Imei] = [Extent2].[Imei] and [Extent1].[CreationDate] = [Extent2].MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` query:

```
select h.Id, h.Imei, h.CreationDate, h.DeviceId,
       sum(cast(aa.value as int)) as num_enrolled
from histories h join
     applications a
     on a.DeviceHistoryId = h.id join
     ApplicationAttributes aa
     on aa.DeviceApplicationId = a.id and
        aa.key = 'EnrolledTotal'
group by h.Id, h.Imei, h.CreationDate, h.DeviceId;
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, but have the following error: "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.". Mean: my Value column don't an int, but nvarchar.

Comment: Replaced with SUM(CAST([Extent4].[Value] AS BIGINT)) as [enrolledTotal] and everything is worked. Thank you.